# Java calling other methods in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have written a worker class looking like this:

```
public final class Worker
{
  private static final int    LOOP_COUNT    = 10;
  private static final int    COMPUTE_COUNT = 1000;
  private static final Random RANDOM        = new Random();
  private static final int    BUFFER_SIZE   = 4;

  /**
   * do a little bit of calculation and write the thread’s name to stdout
   */
  public static void  doSomething()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
          + " doing something: " + i);
      System.out.flush();

      for (int j = 0; j < COMPUTE_COUNT; j++)
      {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        RANDOM.nextBytes(buffer);
        final BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(buffer);
        b1.pow(128);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Afterwards I call the worker with following class:

```
public class SynchronizedMultiMethod
{
  public synchronized void methodOne()  
  {
    Worker.doSomething();
  }

  public void methodTwo()
  {
    Worker.doSomething();
  }
}
```

I start two new threads in my main-method and call the two methods in SynchronizedMultiMethod:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
      {
        final SynchronizedMultiMethod sync = new SynchronizedMultiMethod();

        final Thread t1 = new Thread()
          {
            public void run()
            {   
                sync.methodOne();
            }
          };

        final Thread t2 = new Thread()
          {
            public void run()
            {

              sync.methodTwo();
            }
          };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
      }
}
```

If I execute this code, I get this output:

```
Thread Thread-1 doing something: 0
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 0
Thread Thread-1 doing something: 1
Thread Thread-1 doing something: 2
Thread Thread-1 doing something: 3
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 1
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 2
Thread Thread-1 doing something: 4
...
```

I'm a little bit confused because I thaught that if I use synchronized on an instance method,
the whole instance is blocked for other threads and will be released by leaving the synchronized block.
If I use a second synchronized on methodTwo(), it works fine:

```
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 0
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 1
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 2
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 3
Thread Thread-0 doing something: 4
```

Can anybody tell me how it works? thx!

Comment: calling a synchronized method only blocks other synchronizers on the same instance.  since `methodTwo()` is not synchronized, it is not blocked.

Comment: It should work as you want if `doSomething` is synchronized instead of `methodOne`. About the calculation part, if you just want the threads to take some time there you can try using a `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: John Bollinger's answer can be boiled down to this:  `synchronized(foo) {...}` prevents other threads from doing `synchronized(foo) {...}` for the same object `foo` at the same time.  It does _not_ prevent other threads from doing _anything_ else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken about the meaning and usage of `synchronized`.  If you declare a method `synchronized`, it is functionally equivalent to putting a `synchronized(this) {...}` block around the entire contents of the method body.  This interacts with other synchronized methods of the same object, and with other blocks synchronized on the same object, but it has no effect on other code.

In particular, methods and blocks that are not synchronized on the same object -- or are not synchronized at all -- are not excluded from running concurrently with a synchronized method of a given object.  Thus, `sync.methodTwo()`, which is not synchronized, can run concurrently with `sync.MethodOne()`.  One of many ways to prevent this would be to make `SynchronizedMultiMethod.methodTwo()` synchronized as well.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized keyword in java is used in two ways
1.At Instance level
2.At Class level

In the instance level ,we are passing the instance in the synchronized method like
       synchronized(this)

- public synchronized void methodOne(Worker sWorker)     {
     sWorker.doSomething();   }

In above code we are just passing the instance which we are willing to synchronized.